# Shuffle sets into groups using analytic functions

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I'm trying to find a way on using analytical function in a single query. Here's my problem :

**My data** : Based on similarity records are pre-organized into SETs (shown below).

**My goal** : I'm trying to shuffle the sets into groups such that, as much possible, the records from the same SET are not in the same group.

E.g.:

[image: Sample data]

**What works fine :**

Below is my code which seems to perfectly do what I'm looking for.

```
/**** First update set wise row num ****/
insert into my_set_stage_1
select text,
       set,
       row_number() over(partition by set order by text) as set_sequence
from my_set;

/**** Next add to group using NTILE ****/
insert into my_set_stage_2
select text,
       set,
       set_sequence,
      ntile(10) over(order by set_sequence) as group_id
from my_set_stage_1 s;
```

**My question :**

My actual data is large volume. As you can see, I'm using 2 intermediate table = 2 big queries. Is it possible to use analytical functions to set the group_id in a single query?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just execute those selects without the inserts?

```
select s.text,
       s.set,
       s.set_sequence,
      ntile(10) over(order by s.set_sequence) as group_id
from (
    select text,
           set,
           row_number() over(partition by set order by text) as set_sequence
    from my_set
) s
```

> "if the query execution plan cost would remain same or reduce."

An Explain Plan will show you the cost of executing the SELECT statements. What it won't show you is the overhead of inserting large amounts of data into (temporary?) tables. We would expect the complete cost - the elapsed time to return a result set - to be be reduced.

Obviously sorting large amounts of data is not a cheap exercise. At which point the usual tuning concerns apply. How much data is "high volume"? What system resources (memory, CPUs) do you have at your disposal? Is this a one-off exercise or a recurring task?